# Probablity of 1/512 chance occuring twice within 188 trials

Tags: probability, self-study

I'm curious about what the probability is of the following happening:

An event has a 1/512 success rate, what is the probability of this event succeeding twice within 188 trials?

How would I solve something like this?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: 1. By "twice", do you mean "exactly twice" or "at least twice"? $\ $  2. Can you describe the situation from which your curiosity about this very specific set of numbers arises?

Comment: I have added the self study tag, sorry for the confusion.

1) Exactly twice
2) It came up when I was playing a video game, I got two of the same item within 188 attempts when the drop rate is 1/512. I was curious about how rare that occurrence was.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way such problems are solved is by making use of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

For "success" probability $p$ and $n$ trials, it has probability function (or probability mass function):

$$P(X=x) = {n \choose x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}\,, \quad 0<p<1, x=0,1,2,...,n\,.$$

A problem of the "exactly twice" form is a straight evaluation of a binomial probability function, while "at least twice" can be done by working out the probability of the complementary event.

If the binomial distribution hasn't been covered in your course, you can work it out from first principles, but it would be unusual to give a problem like that to do from first principles.